# How can I paginate in supabase/GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, graphql, pagination, supabase

When I have a query:

```js
{
  postsCollection(first: 10) {
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage,
      hasPreviousPage,
      startCursor,
      endCursor
    }
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        id
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I return only the next and previous cursors. I need to know how many pages there are in total. Furthermore, how can I navigate to an arbitrary page, for example page 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a cursor based pagination example here: https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-graphql-example/blob/master/app/pages/item/%5BpostId%5D.tsx

```js
const ItemRouteQuery = gql(/* GraphQL */ `
  query ItemRouteQuery($postId: BigInt!, $profileId: UUID!) {
    post: postCollection(filter: { id: { eq: $postId } }, first: 1) {
      edges {
        cursor
        node {
          id
          ...FeedItem_PostFragment
          comments: commentCollection(
            first: 15
            orderBy: [{ createdAt: DescNullsLast }]
          ) {
            edges {
              cursor
              node {
                id
                ...CommentItem_CommentFragment
              }
            }
            pageInfo {
              hasNextPage
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`);
```

Regarding `totalCount` it is enabled by default but can be disabled via comment directive, see https://github.com/supabase/pg_graphql/issues/68